# Disable caption of subfigure completely

Tags: spacing, captions, subcaption

I use the `caption` and `subcaption` packages to set up my figures. Sometimes I don't want to display any (sub-) captions at all.

I tried `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}` with an empty caption (`\caption{}`) which works, but the problem is, that **the vertical space between the main-caption and the images is now too big**, because the space for the sub-captions is still "reserved".

How do I fix this? I have a feeling it might be possible with the `\DeclareCaption-Format` command of the `caption` package, but I don't know how.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[list=false]{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.34\textwidth}    
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}   
\caption{}  
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.34\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{With caption labels enabled.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.34\textwidth}    
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}   
\caption{}  
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.34\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{With Subcaptions disabled. Spacing looks bad.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you not need sub-captions than simple don't use  `caption{} in `subfigure` environments .... or not use `subfigure` environments at all and  include graphics directly in figure environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Perhaps `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty, skip=0pt]`?

Comment: Thanks. I removed the captions and labels of the subfigures and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Zarko, you must delete the extraneous empty `caption{}` where you dont want to have neither caption nor space (ie on line 23 and 27).
By this way your`\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}`  is not needed.

The more elaborate suggestion of Bernard dont resolve the problem without removing the unwanted `caption{}`, as some extra space is still added.